# Nth Fibonacci Term JavaScript *New to JS*

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, input, fibonacci

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>Fibonacci Assignment</title>
<head>
    <script>
        function chkInput(){
        var n = parseInt(n1)
        var a,b,r;
        a = 0;
        b = 1;
        r = 1;
            for(var i = 2; i <= n; i++){
                r = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = r;
            }
            alert (r);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"
           id="n1">
    <input type="button"
           value="Enter"
           onclick="chkInput(n1.value)">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to JavaScript and I've been attempting to construct a code for finding the Nth term of the Fibonacci Sequence where the User inputs a number and the sequence runs until the nth number. I have been tasked with using both a function and a for loop for this. However when I run it, no matter what number I input it returns as 1. My questions is why that might be? I'm a student so I just need general direction not the answer. This snippet is what I have so far.

Comment: I sense that this is your homework ;)

Comment: @JayEdwards It is and I’ve been trying to fix it for like a week, I just more or less want to know what I’m doing wrong but the responses so far are helpful

Comment: that's cool, those early days of learning are wrought with these kinds of frustrations! Hope the answers below solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value of element using DOM functions like `document.getElementById("n1").value`

Also your algorithm is wrong it should have  `a = 1;`

```js
function chkInput(){
        var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value)
        var a,b,r;
        a = 1;
        b = 1;
        r = 1;
       
         for(var i = 2; i <= n; i++){
                r = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = r;
                
         }   
            alert (r);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>Fibonacci Assignment</title>
<head>
    <script>
       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"
           id="n1">
    <input type="button"
           value="Enter"
           onclick="chkInput(n1.value)">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't capturing the text input value as a parameter.

You had:

```
checkInput()
```

It should be

```
chkInput(n1)
```

So your line

```
var n = parseInt(n1);
```

Was parsing `undefined`, so the value of n is now NAN (Not a Number), so the for loop never got executed.

```js
function chkInput(n1) {
  var n = parseInt(n1);
  var a, b, r;
  a = 0;
  b = 1;
  r = 1;
  for (var i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    r = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = r;
  }
  alert(r);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1">
<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="chkInput(n1.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done with your assignment.

You have missed to receive the value in the function definition.

Altering **function chkInput(){** to **function chkInput(n1){** will complete your assignment.

Find the your working code snippet below.

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<title>Fibonacci Assignment</title>
<head>
    <script>
        function chkInput(inputValue) {
          var n = parseInt(inputValue)
          var a,b,r;
          a = 0;
          b = 1;
          r = 1;
           for(var i = 2; i <= n; i++){
                r = a + b;
                a = b;
                b = r;
            }
            alert (r);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="n1">
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="chkInput(n1.value)">
</body>
</html>
```